# padding an <a> element inside a <div> to achieve a clickable box

Tags: css

On this website: http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/pg/

I am trying to get the coloured area of each `<div class="awards_square_home">` to be a click-able link by nesting an `<a>` tag inside the `<div>` and adding padding. However I am already using padding on the `<div>` to position the `<a>`. With the padding in this rule:

```
.awards_square_home {
    border: 10px solid rgb(195, 195, 195);
    height: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 90px 20px 20px;
}
```

Now when I add padding to the  element it is not spreading the padding in the way that I desire, which is to to make the entire coloured area of the div click-able.

```
.awards_square_home a {
    padding: 120px 0 20px;
}
```

I am trying to make the from the `<a>` fill this area of the `<div>`:

[image]

Comment: Avoid live websites as an example of your problem - isolated test cases are better.

Comment: the picture represent what you want or what you get?
by colored area, you mean the dark grey or green?

Comment: is there a reason why you don't make the whole block as an `a` and not a `div` and give the `a` a `display: block` ? (you just need to take sure that the elements in `a`are valid children of `a` then.)

Comment: @wazaminator the green

Comment: Have you considered `position: absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0` within the `position:relative`-d `div`? With explicit margin/padding values, you put a lot of knowledge about the container size in.

Answer (score 0):

and why you can't add `<div>` into `<a>` tag?

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

and add your content into `<a>` tag.

Or remove padding from div and set padding only for `<a>` tag.

Comment: because an `div` is not a valid child of  `a`

Comment: Sadly I am having to use HTML4

Comment: the page is in html 4.01 transitional

Comment: @MichalChovanec hmm .. when did that happen :D .. good to know ... anyway it is not a good idea right now. for older browsers, having an default block element inside of an inline element could causes some rendering bugs. (at least i IE i could force some strange behavior, when doing such things)

Comment: you can explicitly set display:block to a element in older browsers too (i am sure it works in IE7 and newer)

Comment: Makes me laugh when people say they "can't use HTML5". Why? Everything you write in 4 will work in 5, you just change the doctype and are open to new possibilities if required

Comment: @MichalChovanec i know this. what i ment is having an element that is by default a `block` element inside an element that is by default an `inline` element and setting them both to `block` had some strange side effects at least in IE. e.g. not correctly updates in rendering (it did not happen always, but i was able to track this down to this) so i don't use this (probably thats the reason why i thought it is still not valid for html5)

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand you, you want your div all to be clickable rather than the text only.

```
<a href="#" class="text220 centertext capitalise_text home_feature_turqoise NG">
    <div class="awards_square_home turqoise podium">
        <span>Best</span>
        <span>University</span>
        <span>Campaign</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VRSJ5/)

Comment: not possible, html doesn't allow a block composent inside an inline composent.

Comment: It does "allow" it. It's not usually a good idea though because it can cause display issues in some browsers. Long as it's tested in the browsers you need it to work in, it's a solution, but in the same way that eval can be a "solution" in JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have fixed the issue by amending the the CSS as follows:

```
.awards_square_home {    
    border: 10px solid #c3c3c3;     
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.awards_square_home a {
    display:block;
    padding: 90px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting background / padding / height on the parent `<div>`, you can just set the `<a>` element to behave like a div and set them there instead:

```
a {
  display: block;
  background-image: url("../images/icons/globe_v3.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 15%;
  padding: 95px 20px 20px 20px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Don't forget to remove these properties from where they currently exist.

Answer (score -1):

if you want the a to fill the div,why do you use padding on the div,and margin on tha a, which the sole purpose is to prevent the a from filling the div?

delete the padding on the a,it should work